# Statistics in Perl Script

Tags: perl, statistics

I have the following question:
I want to create a perl script that reads from a text file (file with several columns of numbers) and calculate some statistics (mean, median, sd, variance). I already built one script, but as I am not in love yet with perl, I can't fix the problems of syntax on it...
Here is my perl script..

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
open(FILEHANDLE, data.txt);
while (<FILEHANDLE>) {
shift @ARGV;
my @array = split(\t,$_);
}
close(FILEHANDLE);
###### mean, sum and size
$N = $sum = 0;
$array[$x-1]; 
$N++;
$sum += $array[$x-1];
###### minimum and the maximum
($min = 0, $max = 0);
$max = $array[$x-1] if ($max < $array[$x-1]), (my@sorted = sort { $a <=> $b } @samples) {
print join(" ",@sorted);
}
##### median
if ($N % 2==1) {
print "$median = $sorted[int($N/2)]\n"; ## check this out
};
else ($median = ($sorted[$N/2] + $sorted[($N/2)-1]) / 2)) { 
print "$median\n"; # check this out
};
##### quantiles 1º and 3º
if $qt1 = $sorted[$r25-1] {
print "\n"; # check this out
};
else $qt1 = $fr*($sorted[$ir] - $sorted[$ir-1]) + $sorted[$ir-1] {
print "\n"; # check this out
};
##### variance
for (my $i=0; 
$i<scalar(@samples); 
$i++) 
{
$Var += ($samples[$i]-$mean)**2;
$Var = $Var/($N-1);
};
###### standard error
($Std = sqrt($Var)/ sqrt($N));
############################################################
print "$min\n";
print "$max\n";
print "$mean\n";
print "$median\n";
print "$qt1\n";
print "$var\n";
print "$std\n";

exit(0);
```

I want to get it working. Please help. THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Comment: This is a mess. I would suggest you make functions, and sort out the errors on a smaller scale. E.g. `sub sum { ... }` You might also be interested to check out some modules at [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org), such as [List::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Util) for min and max, etc.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I'm not allowed to use CPAN modules. I got a head ache when I look at the script. As I said, I'm new on perl and this is too much for my brain. xD. this mess should work, it only need a few loops and counters.

Comment: If this is homework, you should mark it with the homework tag. There are so many errors in this code that there is no way you'll get someone to point them all out. I suggest you go through the errors and fix them one by one. Do not turn off strict and warnings.

Comment: sorry, but i can't read this script. if you're not in love with perl, so, you must be in love with other language. OR if you want help, you need to be more polite to others and make good formatting of your code.

Comment: also, please, check modules like `Statistics::` on CPAN.

Answer (score 4):

Errors in your code:

```
open(FILEHANDLE, data.txt);
```

data.txt needs to be quoted. You are not checking the return value of the open, e.g. `... or die $!`. You *should* use a lexical filehandle and three argument open, e.g. `open my $fh, '<', "data.txt" or die $!`.

```
shift @ARGV;
```

This does nothing except remove the first value from you argument list, which is then promptly discarded.

```
my @array = split(\t,$_);
```

You are using `\t` as a bareword, it should be a regex, `/\t/`. Your `@array` is declared inside a lexical scope of the while loop, and will be undefined outside this block.

```
$N = $sum = 0;
```

Both variables are not declared, which will cause the script to die when you use strict (which is a very good idea). Use `my $N` to solve that. Also, `$N` is not a very good variable name.

```
$array[$x-1];
```

This will do nothing. `$x` is not declared (see above), and also undefined. The whole statement does nothing, it is like having a line `3;`. I believe you will get an error such as `Useless use of variable in void context`.

```
$N++;
```

This increments `$N` to 1, which is a useless thing to do, since you only a few lines above initialized it to 0.

Well.. the list goes on. I suggest you start smaller, use strict and warnings since they are very good tools, and work out the errors one by one. A very good idea would be to make subroutines of your calculations, e.g.:

```
sub sum {
   # code here
   return $sum;
}
```

Go to [perldoc.perl.org](http://perldoc.perl.org/) and read the documentation. Especially useful would be the syntax related ones and [perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html).

Also, you should be aware that this functionality can be found in modules, which you can find at [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org).

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is you have not declared your variables such as `$N`, `$max`, etc.

You need to introduce all new variables with `my` the first time you reference them. Just like you did with `$array` and `$i`. So for example

```
$N = $sum = 0;
```

Should become

```
my( $N, $sum ) = ( 0, 0 );
```

Comment: Thanks Guys!, It's too late for me today. I will try all of your suggestions tomorrow. Thanks again.